# Permanent access to app of dropbox account?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I have an app which links to an dropbox account. I am able to login once and is saves that. But each time it asks whether I want to allow access to the app or not . Is there a way to save this preference as well and provide access to the app permanently ?

Answer (score 1):

Read again https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#android especially "Return to your app after user authorization".

After successful .getSession().finishAuthentication() there is AccessTokenPair tokens = mDBApi.getSession().getAccessTokenPair() which will give You data, which You should save somewhere for later use (You can use SharedPreferences for this).

In start time of application You have to check existance of this saved data, and if it's there, You don't have to call .startAuthentication() again, instead You should call .setAccessTokenPair(access) with saved data as access (look at top of https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/files#android ).